# Align Button To Left Side Of UITableView Cell Programmatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm creating a simple app using Swift 5, Xcode 11, and a ui table view controller. Inside the ui table view, I want 2 buttons: One button on the left of my table view, the other on the right. I have tried many other related/similar question's answers, but all of them failed(probably because 1. Too Old, 2. Answer written in OBJ-C).

Here's my Table View Controller:

```swift
import UIKit

@objcMembers class CustomViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tag = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // 3
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tag = tag + 1

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "themeCell", for: indexPath) as! ThemeCell
        var cellButton: UIButton!


        cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 30))
        cell.addSubview(cellButton)
        cell.img.image = UIImage(named: SingletonViewController.themes[indexPath.row])
        cell.accessoryView = cellButton
        cellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cellButton.tag = tag
        return cell
    }

}
```

Here's what I'm currently getting:
[image: IMG]

Comment: share the screenshot of what you are currently receiving.

Comment: why don't you add those button with "themeCell" .xib file?

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com See my edits

Comment: try like this  cell.contentView.addSubview(cellButton) maybe work

Comment: @RuchiMakadia It doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Aamir the reason I don't do that is because after I set the constraints for the button, I can only see the image view in specific device sizes. It's weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add below code for apply constraint worked

```
let cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
cellButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cell.addSubview(cellButton)
cell.accessoryView = cellButton
cellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

cellButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
cellButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
cellButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
cellButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

Comment: When you set  `cellButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` the frame setting is ignored it doesn't have any effect

Comment: yes you right you can just set like UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve right and left align button from constraints.
Below is my code to align view right or left.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        let leftButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        leftButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(leftButton)
        
        leftButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = leftButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20)
        let verticalConstraint = leftButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        let widthConstraint = leftButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        let heightConstraint = leftButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
        
        let rightButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        rightButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(rightButton)
        
        rightButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraintRight = rightButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20)
        let verticalConstraintRight = rightButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        let widthConstraintRight = rightButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        let heightConstraintRight = rightButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraintRight, verticalConstraintRight, widthConstraintRight, heightConstraintRight])
        
        
    }
```

[![Left and Right Aligned View Constraints][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMJ8N.jpg

Comment: One more thing, why does the button go off the line in the table view cell?(my button goes off the line of my table view when I tested it)

Comment: off the line ? means ?

Comment: off the line vertically ?

Answer (score 2):

As the cell is getting reuse, you have to put buttons in your xib file. You should not make a button every time and add it in a cell. Try this by adding a button in xib.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ThemeCell: UITableViewCell { 


  //MARK:- Initialize View

  private let button : UIButton = {

   let button = UIButton()
   button.setTitle("Hello", .normal)
   button.backgroundColor = .red
   button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   return button

  }()

  //MARK:- View Life Cycle

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    setup()

}

override func awakeFromNib() {

    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    selectionStyle = .none


}

//MARK:- User Defined Function

private func setup() {

   addSubView(button)
   button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

   button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
   button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true


}
}
```

You can use AutoLayout Constraints like this to setup the button. No need to call it in the `cellForRow` method.